# asp.net MVC partial with dynamic inherits class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view that is shared between two controllers and I'm trying to find a way to change what it inherits from depending on which view it is being called from or which controller.

IE:

my current partial is started like so:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVCProject.Controllers.PurchasingOrderViewModel>" %>
```

and i would like it to also be able to inherit from another class because of needing the same info in two separate controllers

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to introduce a common interface or an abstract class for MVCProject.Controllers.PurchasingOrderViewModel and your other model like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVCProject.Controllers.IOrderViewModel>" %>
```

Comment: yeah that's what i was originally thinking, was hoping there was something slightly easier, although that's not too bad. Thanks